# Why is the value of my many to many field zero even though it contains users?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am currently creating a debate website but I'm having a problem with the liking system. In my models I have a class called Debate which has likes, which likes being a many-to-many field. On my admin page it says that the likes field has a certain amount of users - yet when I print the count of likes out - it shows 0.

I have already tried to change the parameters on my likes model, manually set the users value in the model, and checked if I was printing the value out incorrectly, but none of them seemed to help my problem.

IN MODELS FILE

```
class Debate(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length =20 , blank=True, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=True, default='')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='likes', blank=True)
```

IN ADMIN FILE

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Debate, Comments
class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'like_count',)
    def like_count(self,obj):
        return obj.likes.all().count()
admin.site.register(Debate, InfoAdmin)
```

ADMIN PAGE IN A SINGLE DEBATE'S LIKES SECTION(debate title is h)

```
Likes: UserProfile object(5)
       UserProfile object(9)
```

ADMIN PAGE DEBATES LIST

```
ID                          TITLE               LIKE COUNT
13                            h                      0
```

This is the like output when a debate is just created. You would expect the like count to print 2 since there are two objects but instead it prints 0.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. You may want to add additional tags to your question. Eg "python" and "django" might be good choices. This allows experts in those technologies to see your question more easily.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you see in the admin page? May be the UserProfiles listed are not selected.